# Header Button Chance Polylang Elementor

Tags: plugin-development, menus, headers, buttons, plugin-polylang

Currently, I am making a Bilingual website, and I made a button on the header as well, and I want to make the button bilingual as well, but I don't know how could I change its language because it is not part of the menu.
I use Polylang and Elementor.

[image]

Comment: Same problem here, Polylang recognises all of my menu headings links except for the menu **button**. It seems because it is a different class of ID that it can't detect it. Is there a way to add it manually in WP-Dashboard APPEARANCE > MENUS > ? EDIT: I suppose the work around is to change the button content into a standard link, then format to look like a button with CSS.. seems like an awkward workaround though

Comment: I have the same issue, Did you find any solution ?